# Jquery Mobile design inconsistent using WebView

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

Throwing a simple app together just to try and get an HTML 5 app to run as a standalone.

On my Nexus 5 the sliders look like this:
[look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgY1w.jpg).

However, in the emulator and on my girlfriend's Note 2 the sliders [look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPVSF.png)

All of the files are stored locally in the assets folder. Everything else works fine including Jquery elements like buttons and text boxes, as well as the footer and even popup dialogs. Perhaps the sliders aren't supported in different versions of the browser?

Comment: This might have to to with the fact that KitKat now has a chrome based WebView, not WebKit.

Comment: I just did a test and visited the Jquery website on the same emulator. Under the slider section it looks perfect, but still looks messed up in my app.


This is using the android browser, not Chrome